# Best practice for default property values in spring beans

Tags: java, spring, tdd, spring-test

To make beans testable I usually use the following pattern:

```
 class SomeClass {

    private Something field = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (field == null)
            field = someClass.someValue; //(this may throw an exception, that's why it's here)
    }

    //Notice: this is package local
    void setField(Something value) {
        field = value;
    }
}
```

I use this pattern very often so I have a default behaviour and a behaviour to use in test. The someClass.someValue often will be something nasty like a static method from legacy code, or something that throws exceptions or both.

Someone argues this is a bit of a hack, but I don't see anything bad in it.

What are the disadvantages of using this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you are using is in fact an anti-pattern: you are coupling your code to legacy constructs, implementation details, etc.

And that goes against the principles of Dependency Injection (DI) and Inversion of Control (IoC).

Spring, on the other hand, is a proponent of DI and IoC.

Thus a better pattern would be to always use DI for your dependencies and remove the use of `@PostConstruct` for such cases.

If you need to invoke static factory methods to create your `Something` object, that's not a problem: simply use a `factory-method` or a custom `FactoryBean` in XML configuration or a standard `@Bean` method in JavaConfig. Then have the `Something` object injected into `SomeClass` as a required property (e.g., as a constructor argument).